# Errors SQL Statement ignored and ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here on stored PL/SQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am fairly new to SQL and am having trouble resolving these two errors.

The idea is that when the procedure is ran, it will try to find any data with matching order_key, part_key and supplier_key. if there is no matching data found then the insert statement is good to go, however if matching data is found, then display a message saying so.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INSERT_ITEM(order_key IN NUMBER,
                                        part_key IN NUMBER,
                                        supplier_key IN NUMBER,
                                        quantity IN NUMBER,
                                        price IN NUMBER,
                                        discount IN NUMBER,
                                        tax IN NUMBER) IS

ITEM_CHECK LINEITEM%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO ITEM_CHECK
    FROM LINEITEM
    WHERE L_ORDERKEY = order_key
    AND L_PARTKEY = part_key
    AND L_SUPPKEY = supplier_key;
    
    IF ITEM_CHECK IS NOT NULL THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error! An order already exists with the same part manufactured by the same supplier');
    END IF;
    
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO LINEITEM VALUES(order_key, part_key, supplier_key, COUNT(L_LINENUMBER) + 1, quantity, price, discount, tax, '', '', SYSDATE  + 1, SYSDATE , SYSDATE  + 8, '', '', '');
END;
/
COMMIT;
END INSERT_ITEM;

EXECUTE INSERT_ITEM(1, 1, 1, 50, 200, 0.04, 0.02);
```

I am fairly sure

> Error(26,72): PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here

is due to the `COUNT` in the select statement, however I have not been able to find anything about what is causing

> Error(26,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are inserting the record only if it doesn't exists , I don't understand what are you trying to do with `COUNT(L_LINENUMBER) + 1` ?

Comment: Regarding the "statement ignored" error in the stack, that is the PL/SQL compiler rejecting the SQL statement due to the preceding error.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do it that way.

Create a composite UNIQUE index on those 3 KEY columns.

- if such a combination does not exist, row will be inserted
- otherwise, error will be raised. Not as a message, but "real" error which you can / should handle in EXCEPTION handling section of your PL/SQL procedure. Exception name is DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX